# How can I have 2 users working on the same PC at the same time

Tags: windows-xp, remote-access

I have a pc/machine that has its own ip address and it can be connected to by certain external PC's through our firewall.
User A has a RDP connection from say Germany directly to the PC - his ip number is allowed through our firewall to connect to the PC. He now wants User B to connect at the same time so that User B can see what User A is doing on the screen at the same time and maybe take over the screen to put his input in. I know that you cannot have 2 RDP connections at the same time but what would be the easiest solution to this. I want User A to keep his RDP connection, but I am unsure of what to suggest so that User B can see what is going on at the same time. The Users are not happy to use Real VNC, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that you cannot have 2 RDP connections at the same time

Server without terminal server - and that is what I assume this is - allows 2 administrator accounts at the same time, so that is already wrong.

> ut I am unsure of what to suggest so that User B can see what is going on at the same time.

RDP. User B Logs in, goes to RDP management, then iggiebacks on User A's session - that is a standard feature supported by RDP.

> The Users are not happy to use Real VNC

Understandable given the orrific support for multi monitors and the really crappy speed that comes when you make screenshots (dramatized).

Unless that is a workstaiotn (Windows 7) it is already there. Both msut be administrators, obviously.

Comment: You know very little, you know? - Thank you for the update, however was this comment a joke or sarcasm ?

Comment: A comment, direcltly before quoting something oyu said you know which is wrong.